# How can I get last characters of Aadhar Number using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have one Aadhar Number.

`var temb ="xxxxxxxx5267"`

I need to get last 4 digits `(5267)`

I had tried `(.{3})\s*$` it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slice method with negative sign (matches characters by reverse):

```js
var temb ="xxxxxxxx5267";

console.log(temb.slice(-4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
[0-9]{4}$
```

Check demo here : https://regex101.com/r/etasd5/1/

Comment: Or you can modify yours from  (.{3})\s*$   to  (.{4})\s*$

Answer (score 1):

The regex works well. Did you use the right method for [regex group capturing](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)?

```js
const temb ="xxxxxxxx5267"
const res = temb.match(/(.{4})\s*$/g)

console.log(res[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex replacement here:

```js
const temb ="xxxxxxxx5267"
const num = temb.replace(/^.*(\d{4})$/, "$1");
console.log(num);
```

Another variant:

```js
const temb ="xxxxxxxx5267"
const num = temb.replace(/^.*(?=\d{4}$)/, "");
console.log(num);
```